# How to keep machine learning models relevant?

Tags: machine-learning

I plan to build a recommendation system for training.

As my understanding is for now, if I build and train a machine learning model the prediction it produces are based on my training data. But if I have a setting with a small but fast chaning data set like a small online shop this means, that my model will be outdated pretty soon.

For example: If a new user (no present data) likes a product, this data will not immediately be available in by ML model. So the new user will get the same recommendations as long as I do not retrain my ML model.
This does not sound very practical to me.

What would be a good way to update my model fast as I get new information on my users (implicit feedback)?

I am aware of reinforced ML, but this does not seem to be very common as for today. So I guess there must be a different way to address this problem...

Would be very happy if you could give me some hints or buzzwords how I could solve this problem.
Or maybe I have a misunderstanding of the base principals?

Comment: This question isn't suited for Stack Overflow, because it's not about programming or debugging. You could try the sister site [stats.SE], though I'm not sure it's appropriate there either because of the broad scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right that the prediction of any **machine learning model is based on the training data**.

So if your data is constantly changing and you want to update your machine learning model as well, you can do the following steps :-

- Whenever any new user's activity is added in your database table, take that data and add to your training data. For this purpose you need to plan how well you can structure the table and save your data.
- Then set a cron job (cron job is time-based job scheduler that runs your script(job) on the basis of the time you set).
- Set a threshold value like whenever this much activity is increased in the database or this much data is increased , run the cron job or run the script.
- In your cron job, the script will do three things.

  - First it will take the new data from the database , prepare it in the format of training data.
  - Then train the saved machine learning model on the new data prepared in the above steps.
  - After the training is finished, replace the old machine learning model with the new one.

In this way, you can easily keep your model up-to-date.